# Why is this subset finite?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra, semisimple-lie-algebras, semi-simple-rings

We are given that $R$ is a ring with identity, and that $R$ is left semisimple, i.e. $R$ can be decomposed into a sum of minimal left ideals of $R$ ($R=\bigoplus_{n\in S} I_n$). What I'm confused about is why the cardinality of the set of projections of $1$ into each $I_n$ with such a projection being nonzero is finite, i.e. why we can say
$$1=1_{n_1}+\cdots+1_{n_k}$$
For some $k\in \mathbb{N}$ and $1_{n_i}\in I_{n_i}$. Here is the text I am looking at. It is from Knapp's Advanced Algebra, Chapter 2

> [image: ref]

Comment: The definition of a direct sum only involves finite sums of elements of $R$, even if there are infinitely many summands in the direct sum. Infinite sums of elements of $R$ don't make sense unless there is a notion of convergence.

Comment: The user in the duplicate has pretty much exactly the same problem, and the solution in the duplicate is pretty much exactly the same...

Answer (score 4):

That’s just what a direct sum is. Any element of a direct sum only has finitely many non-zero components. More symbolically, an element of $\oplus_{n\in S}I_i$ is a tuple $(a_n)_{n\in S}$ with $a_n\in I_n$ such that $a_n=0$ for all but finitely many $n$.